# Need to screen scrape browser as opposed to webpage

Tags: screen-scraping

I have a webpage that needs to be scraped to look for certain text. The problem is it's not really webscraping that I am trying to achieve. The website is opened by a separate process. I am specifically talking about a webpage but really, it is more of a universal screen scraping issue. Conceptually, It's more like I am scraping the browser instead of the page itself. Is there a program that can scan any open process and look for and match text? To put it another way, it would be like having a separate program from the browser's built-in ctrl+f find function. I just need a simple utility to tell my if a given text is present in a boolean type fashion. I realize this is a very broad question but I haven't been able to find anything about it. Maybe I don't quite know how to articulate it in a Google search because my research keeps coming up empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the structure of the page, like it's always Google search results, or always an Amazon product, you might look at Selenium or one of the many Chrome screen-scraping add-ons.

If you want to grab data off of any page without knowing the format in advance, I don't know a way.